# Why does a LINQ query in an expression throw this error?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, uwp

**The premise:**
I am a new to c# and StackOverflow.

I have a list in which the user can search, has filters, and has sorting.

I query the original collection and feed it to the collection that is bound to the view.

While the user is searching (async) I query and replace the collection completely.
When the user  filters/sorts I query, compare and add/remove from displayed collection.

**The question:**

Is there a way to make these queries less verbose using another technique?
This piece of code only contains code for one filter case...
This gets real lenghty real fast and repeats parts of the queries often.

I am not experienced enough to know if the following code is the most performant approach, but it works.

```
...
else if ( Filter == "show all" )
{
    if ( Sort == "Quantity" )
    {
        if (SearchTxt.Length > 1) // searchbox is not empty
        {
            if (SearchTxt== _oldSearchTxt )
            {
                // User has typed in search, perform normal query
                // by filter, sort and searchtxt
            }
            else
            {
                // User is typing in search, perform async query
                // by filter, sort and searchtxt 
            }
        }
        else // searchbox is empty
        {
                // perform normal query
                // by filter, sort
        }
    }
    else if ( Sort == "Rating" )
    {
        if (SearchTxt.Length > 1) // searchbox is not empty
        {
            if (SearchTxt== _oldSearchTxt )
            {
                // User has typed in search, perform normal query
                // by filter, sort and searchtxt
            }
            else
            {
                // User is typing in search, perform async query
                // by filter, sort and searchtxt 
            }
        }
        else // searchbox is empty
        {
                // perform normal query
                // by filter, sort
        }
    }
    else // Sort == "Name"
    {
        if (SearchTxt.Length > 1) // searchbox is not empty
        {
            if (SearchTxt== _oldSearchTxt )
            {
                // User has typed in search, perform normal query
                // by filter, sort and searchtxt
            }
            else
            {
                // User is typing in search, perform async query
                // by filter, sort and searchtxt 
            }
        }
        else // searchbox is empty
        {
                // perform normal query
                // by filter, sort
        }
    }
}
_oldSearchTxt = SearchTxt;
```

I have tried to put parts of queries in an Expression but it throws me an error:

```
Expression<Func<MyClassObject, bool>> ItIsFlagged = x => x.IsFlagged.Equals(true);
// the query 
InventoryVM.ReplaceWith( new GroupedObservableCollection<string, MyClassObject>( s => s.Brand,
    Inventory.Where( ItIsFlagged )
    .Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(Searchtxt))
    , Comparer
);
```

throws

```
"Error  CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyApp.Models.MyObjectClass, bool>>' to 'System.Func<MyApp.Models.MyObjectClass, bool>"
```

Examples I have found indicate it should work the way I implemented it. What I understand from the error is an object mismatch. I tried casting but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq's `Where` function expects a `Func<T, bool>` (`T` in your case is `MyClassObject`) but you've supplied an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, change the code to look like this:

```
Func<MyClassObject, bool> ItIsFlagged = x => x.IsFlagged.Equals(true);
```

Also, you don't have to repeat the search code for all of the filter options, you can do something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Name = "John", Age = 51 },
        new Person { Name = "Smith", Age = 22 },
    };

    Console.Write("Sort By (age, name):");
    var sortBy = Console.ReadLine();

    if (sortBy == "age")
        people = people.OrderBy(p => p.Age);
    else if (sortBy == "name")
        people = people.OrderBy(p => p.Name);

    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} - {person.Age}");
    }
}
```

A few suggestions:

- Consider using an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) for the sort options, or at least use constants instead of magic strings.
- Take a look at [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), it's important to use a consistent naming convention.
- `MyClassObject` is a very bad name for a class, please don't use it.

Comment: Thank you very much Encryptor!
I get the sort option string from the xaml objects name.
The events' sender parameter is sent to the viewmodel and is used there to get the name so I can use one method for all checkboxes instead of many methods. It seemed like a good idea to keep code concise.
Maybe I'm going the wrong way in doing so, still learning. 
The code I provided is kind of pseudocode. 
Pasting from Visual Studio was a mess, so I wrote it out by hand.
I dont really use MyClassObject in the project.

Comment: Also, maybe I'm missing something, but the sorting example you provided doesn't group the collection.
The query uses the filter "wheres"  flagged, unflagged or all items, then "wheres" the searchstring,  then sort into a grouped collection. 3 filter options, 3 sorting options, search or no search. 
I'm using a Listview.Itemtemplate and Listview.Groupstyle Headertemplate

Comment: @Hidde you can group the collection by using `GroupBy` method: `var grouped = people.GroupBy(p => p.Age);`